# How to turn a python shell into a android application

Tags: android, python, application-design

I have never made an app before... I only know python and a bit of java... I was wondering is it possible to make an app using python? My app is a translation app for deaf people to be able to communicate with hearing people. How would I go about it?An example one of my files is (sorry if my code is sloppy):

import time
    import os
    import sys
    from easygui import *
    import pygame as pygame

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((89, 112))
os.chdir("/Users/marcellobachechi/Desktop/learn-asl")
tf = open("spelspeed.spd","r")
speed = tf.readline()
# def selectword(a):
#   a = m
#   return a
m = enterbox(msg="what do you want to spell?",image="fingerspell.gif")
if m == "cancel":
        sys.exit()
        os.system("python startasl.py")
while m == "" or m == " " or m == "null" or m == 'NoneType' or len(m) <= 0:
    sys.exit()
    os.system("python startasl.py")


mains = len(m)


l = list(m)
if speed == "slow":
    speeds = 1.5
    print('work')
elif speed == "fast":
    speeds = 0.5
    print('work')
else:
    speeds = 1.0
    print('work')

for element in l:
    pars = element.split(',')
    parts = str(pars)
    nparts = parts.replace("['","")
    flarts = nparts.replace("']","")
    print (flarts)
    name = str(flarts) + ".gif"

    ##############################
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.init()

    myimage = pygame.image.load(name)
    imagerect = myimage.get_rect()
    black = (255,255,255,255)
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(myimage, imagerect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(speeds)




yes = "yes"
rsts = buttonbox(msg="Do you wish to restart?",choices=("yes","no"))
if rsts == yes:
        os.system("python fingerspelltranslator.py")
        pygame.display.quit()
else:
    pygame.display.quit()
    os.system("python startasl.py")

pygame.display.quit()
#os.system("python startasl.py")
```

How could i turn this into a frame work that I could pull all my outputs onto the screen? How do I make a gui? How do I display images in a GUI? Sorry if this is trivial!! I am only 14 and just started programming 5 months ago. So I am still very new and I might do somethings a bit sloppy. Thank you for all your help!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to develop Android apps in Python using [SL4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) (Scripting Layer for Android) and other complementing frameworks.

Refer to [this](https://ep2013.europython.eu/conference/talks/developing-android-apps-completely-in-python) Euro Python tutorial that provides an introduction to developing Android Apps using Python.

Comment: Thank you I was wondering if there is an app to turn that into an iphone app